# Scroll the datagrid down or up to selected index row flex

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, actionscript, flex3

I am performing a find operation in a datagrid on one of the columns. After I find the row containing the item, I make that as the selected index row, which highlights it. But now I also want to scroll the datagrid down or up (if the item is out of screen scope) to show that selected item automatically on this find operation.

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have you tried the `scrolltoindex()` method? Take a look at [Anuj Gakhar's article](http://www.anujgakhar.com/2007/12/28/flex-how-to-pre-select-an-item-in-datagrid/#comments) on using `scrolltoindex()` with a datagrid.

Here's the example from the article:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<mx:Application xmlns:mx="http://www.adobe.com/2006/mxml" layout="absolute"
initialize="doInit();" creationComplete="setSelectedItem()">
<mx:Script>
<![CDATA[
import mx.collections.ArrayCollection;

// this holds the grid data
[Bindable]
private var myData:ArrayCollection = new ArrayCollection();
// change this name here to change the selected item on load
[Bindable]
private var initialFName:String = "Joe9";

private function doInit():void
{
myData.addItem({fname:"Joe",lname:"Bloggs"});
myData.addItem({fname:"Joe1",lname:"Bloggs"});
myData.addItem({fname:"Joe2",lname:"Bloggs"});
myData.addItem({fname:"Joe3",lname:"Bloggs"});
myData.addItem({fname:"Joe4",lname:"Bloggs"});
myData.addItem({fname:"Joe5",lname:"Bloggs"});
myData.addItem({fname:"Joe6",lname:"Bloggs"});
myData.addItem({fname:"Joe7",lname:"Bloggs"});
myData.addItem({fname:"Joe8",lname:"Bloggs"});
myData.addItem({fname:"Joe9",lname:"Bloggs"});
}

private function setSelectedItem():void
{
var gData:Object = dGrid.dataProvider;
for(var i:Number=0; i < gData.length; i++)
{
var thisObj:Object = gData.getItemAt(i);
if(thisObj.fname == initialFName)
{
dGrid.selectedIndex = i;
//sometimes scrollToIndex doesnt work if validateNow() not done
dGrid.validateNow();
dGrid.scrollToIndex(i);
}
}
}
]]>
</mx:Script>

<mx:DataGrid id="dGrid"  dataProvider="{myData}"  visible="true">
<mx:columns>
<mx:DataGridColumn dataField="fname" headerText="FirstName" />
<mx:DataGridColumn dataField="lname" headerText="LastName" />
</mx:columns>
</mx:DataGrid>

</mx:Application>
```